# How to install RealVNC on fedora arm 23?

Tags: vnc, fedora

I use Fedora 23 ARM on a Raspberry Pi 2,
with Xfce as a desktop environment.
I want to install RealVNC. Can you help me ?

Comment: Do you particularly need RealVNC, or will any VNC do? Are you looking for a client or a server?

Comment: Yes i need RealVNC because i want  to stream omxplayer remotely, and RealVNC solve the problem on raspbian.

Comment: I need RealVNC server of course

Comment: You can play omxplayer remotely with the RealVNC server which is installed by default in Raspbian. You simply enable it from the Raspberry Pi Configuration app, and you should see the VNC icon appear in the top right to show it's running.
If you click on this icon, go to Options > Troubleshooting and enable "experimental direct capture mode", this will allow you to capture directly-rendered screen content, such as that displayed by omxplayer.

Comment: Ah, I see. You need RealVNC's [experimental and proprietary](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-minecraft) "direct connect" feature.

Answer (score 1):

For most use, you could use TigerVNC, which is open source and available in Fedora.

The "experimental direct capture" RealVNC feature you want, however, is only included in the proprietary RealVNC software. There is a download available, but for ARM only for Debian currently. (See https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/raspberrypi/). They make RPMs, but only for x86. You might have success in [asking RealVNC nicely](https://www.realvnc.com/contact-us/) to make a Fedora version.

Or, you *could* download the .deb and convert to rpm using [alien](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alien-pkg-convert/). (I don't know how this fits with their licensing terms, so, mind that.)

Comment: I had alreday convert realVNC package to rpm and i tryed to install him using rmp -ivh , but he generate a dependency error:

Comment: Error: Dependencies required:
Libbcm_host.so is required for realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf
Libmmal.so is required for realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf
Libmmal_components.so is required for realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf
Libmmal_core.so is required for realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf
Libmmal_util.so is required for realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf
Libmmal_vc_client.so is required for realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.ar

Comment: but, I found these libraries already installed !!!! using ldconfig

Comment: Yeah, alien doesn't always translate that stuff well. You might try the "nodeps" flag to rpm and see what happens.

Comment: this is waht i get after runnig rpm -ivh realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf.rpm --nodeps:
"Preparation   ################################# [100%]
The realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf package is intended for a different architecture
The / realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf installation file conflicts with the file of the filesystem-3.2-35.fc23.armv7hl package"

Comment: The / usr / bin file of the realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf installation conflicts with the file of the packages filesystem-3.2-35.fc23.armv7hl
The / usr / lib file of the realvnc-vnc-server-6.0.3.27095-2.armhf installation conflicts with the file of the packages filesystem-3.2-35.fc23.armv7hl

Comment: Yeah, so, that's probably not going to work, unfortunately. I think your options are: 1) ask RealVNC for a Fedora build of their software (since they're the only ones who can do it), or 2) go back to the root of what you want to do and find a different approach. Streaming video over VNC seems non-optimal in any case.

Comment: Thank's mattdm i had asked RealVNC support , but unfortunately they apologized to create a fedora version.